# Vertical Menu/Submenu with jQuery conditions

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, submenu

I am looking to have the following conditions added to my existing page. Btw, everything currently seems to be working fine and can be seen here live at: http://www.ceramictilepro.com/Ceramic-Tile-And-Grout-Tips.php

1) When the above linked is clicked, the page will have a vertical menu/submenu with only the menu visible (currently all menus/submenus are expanded).

2) When selected menu is clicked, submenu is expanded and will be visible (currently works so no change here)

3) When submenu is clicked, new page opens. (this currently works too)

4) here is where I need help, I would like the new page to close all other menus except for the menu where the selected submenu was clicked.

note: selected links are highlighted with a red background for easier navigation. (this remains the same, no change needed here)

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/AWahuXe/10/edit)

Here is the current working jQuery

```
$.each([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], function (index) {
$(".toggle" + index).click(function () {
    $(".submenu" + index).slideToggle("fast", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
});


$(function () {
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('_current_highlight_button');
    }
});
});
$(function () {
var split = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var mnurl = split[split.length - 1];
mnurl = '#';
$(' a[href="' + mnurl + '"]').addClass("_current_highlight_button");
}); // mnurl='.php goes here';
```

thank you for any suggestions :)

Comment: could "_current_highlight_button" be used with jQuery as a way to identify the last submenu link that was clicked? If so, then the code would need to keep that submenu open and close the "others". what do you think? of course this is based on all submenus to be closed as default position.

Comment: Yeah, looking at your live site I realized that you already had a method for highlighting the clicked link in red.  I used that same code to come up with a way to identify which sub menu to keep open.  Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

```
$(function () {
  var selected;
  $('.vmenu li a').click(function(e){
    $('.vmenu ul').not($(this).parent().next('ul')).css('display','none');
  });
  $('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).prop('href') == window.location.href) {
        $(this).addClass('_current_highlight_button');
        selected = $(this).parent().parent();
    }
  });
  $('.vmenu ul').not(selected).css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: Hi Trevor and thanks for the help. #4 is basically saying to only have the selected menu/submenu expanded while all others are to be closed. Hope that clears. The fiddle has 4 menus/submenus, so basically only 1 menu/submenu will be expanded when the new page loads after the submenu link is clicked. Prolly a better way to explain :)

Comment: @user2844139 Okay well check out my update.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Note this should work with the submenus.  Now I'm not sure if your looking for all of them to be closed except for the one clicked when clicking the menus..  But i'll get something that deals with that too.

Comment: Hi Trevor, yes I'm looking for all other submenus to be closed. It would be nice to only have the selected submenu expanded while the remaining 3 submenus are closed. btw, thanks for the jQuery you posted above :)

Comment: Just tried it, no luck, all submenus are closed when the selected submenu link is clicked. you can see it live here http://www.ceramictilepro.com/Ceramic-Tile-And-Grout-Tips.php note: please click only the top vertical menu to select the submenu as i'm working on updating the other 3 menus/submenus

Comment: when submenu is clicked, the selected link does not load, then the submenu closes, you can see it live on the above link.

Comment: @user2844139 make sure to take out the `e.preventDefault` from  your jQuery that makes it so the link does not load.  I only put that in the fiddle so that it would not try to go to a link that didn't exist.  Take a look at my latest update.. To accomplish opening the link on a new page your going to need to preserve the information through your link.

Comment: ok, didn't know that, "e.preventDefault();" has been removed. no luck.

Comment: @user2844139 http://jsbin.com/UDiJiBu/6/edit look at this code, its going to the links for me.  That should at least load the links for you, you'll still have to work on preserving the clicked sub menu through the new link.

Comment: ok, you're making great progress! the links now work!!! now just need the selected submenu to stay open and will be good to go! you can see it live.

Comment: @user2844139 okay that took a while, but I think I have a solution for you.  Check my answer now.  If this answer worked out for you please mark your question as answered.  Thanks